# Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined (on p5js editor)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to use firebase service on p5js editor. I followed its documentation on how to set up and initiate the Firebase, but I still got error "firebase is no defined"...

Here are my codes:

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  var config = {
    apiKey: "omit",
    authDomain: "omit",
    databaseURL: "omit",
    projectId: "omit",
    storageBucket: "omit",
    messagingSenderId: "omit"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.6.0/firebase.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi whis! Welcome to StackOverflow!. The code snipped you posted doesn't say `firebase is not defined` It just says that the version you are using is a development build.

Comment: Hi Ahmad, thanks for your reply! I am a beginner to this and don't really understand why these two consoles gave different result...

Answer (score 1):

I think it should work but you have to put the script
`<script src="sketch.js"></script>`
outside the body tag. It is not where it suppose to be.

Comment: the script tag can be placed anywhere in within the HTML body.